# What's the best way to pull all the Metadata types from the Salesforce?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, java, list-metadata, metadata-relationship

I have used describeMetadata() call to fetch the xml names but it's showing only few out of what we have in the [Metadata coverage url](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50). I was wondering if there is a way to pull all the Metadata types of an organization.

If there is something that I'm missing, please share your best practices for retrieving all the Metadata types. This would really help me achieve my application goals.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the describeMetadata is so "small" is that there's a lot of types that are grouped together, such as Settings. To complete the list, call listMetadata for each type that has subcategories. For example, listMetadata(Settings) will get AccountSettings, IdeaSettings, etc. For example, in Salesforce DX:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -u myalias -m Settings
```

Using listMetadata also means you won't need to use wildcards, for example on all ApexClass entries:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -u myalias -m ApexClass
```